# Installing two different versions of grunt on one machine

Tags: javascript, build, npm, gruntjs

I'm contributing to two projects that both require different versions of Grunt:

- Project A requires Grunt v0.3.2
- Project B requires Grunt v0.4.1

Both projects have separate workspaces.

I currently have Grunt v0.4.1 installed on my machine; however I can't seem to run grunt on Project A since it detects the gruntfile differently.  I could migrate Project A from grunt v0.3->0.4, however I feel there could be a better solution out there in the meantime.

How would I go about solving this conflict?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Grunt 0.3 used to require a global install, but with 0.4 you install the cli globally (`npm install grunt-cli`). This should still work with 0.3 if you install the cli globally, and then the 0.3 version locally (like 0.4 does).

So to summarize:

- `npm uninstall grunt -g` to remove the old global grunt version
- `npm install grunt-cli -g` ensure the cli is installed globally
- `npm install grunt@0.3` into your your 0.3 project

Comment: That worked beautifully :)  I'm able to get both projects running.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, you can also use the `--save-dev` and commit the 0.3 dependency to the package.json if you don't plan on updating anytime soon.